# Why can't my pip update no matter how much I fiddle with it? ImportError was reported

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

When I use pip to download something, for example

```
pip install numpy
```

At this time, it will always show a notice reminding me that pip can be updated

```
[notice] A new release of pip available: 22.2.1 -> 22.3.1
[notice] To update, run: C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

When I entered the command it asked me to enter, the command prompt collecting pip, which then displayed a long list of information and exceptions

```
Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:\users\MyName\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (22.2.1)
Collecting pip
  Using cached pip-23.0-py3-none-any.whl (2.1 MB)
Installing collected packages: pip
  Attempting uninstall: pip
    Found existing installation: pip 22.2.1
    Uninstalling pip-22.2.1:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-22.2.1
  Rolling back uninstall of pip
  Moving to c:\users\MyName\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\scripts\pip.exe
   from C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-yaigaesv\pip.exe
  Moving to c:\users\MyName\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\scripts\pip3.9.exe
   from C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-yaigaesv\pip3.9.exe
  Moving to c:\users\MyName\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\scripts\pip3.exe
   from C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-yaigaesv\pip3.exe
  Moving to c:\users\MyName\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages\pip-22.2.1.dist-info\
   from C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\~ip-22.2.1.dist-info
  Moving to c:\users\MyName\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages\pip\
   from C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\~ip
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 167, in exc_logging_wrapper
    status = run_func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 247, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 461, in run
    installed = install_given_reqs(
  File "C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\__init__.py", line 73, in install_given_reqs
    requirement.install(
  File "C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\req_install.py", line 752, in install
    scheme = get_scheme(
  File "C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pip\_internal\locations\__init__.py", line 244, in get_scheme
    from . import _distutils
ImportError: cannot import name '_distutils' from 'pip._internal.locations' (C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pip\_internal\locations\__init__.py)
```

I checked with a search engine and most of the solutions suggested that I should enter the following command to force a pip reinstallation.

```
python -m pip install -U --force-reinstall pip
```

But when I entered it, I found the same error message appeared. And based on ImportError, I found the first few lines on it by looking up the init code.I don't know if it's useful.

```
def get_scheme(
    dist_name: str,
    user: bool = False,
    home: Optional[str] = None,
    root: Optional[str] = None,
    isolated: bool = False,
    prefix: Optional[str] = None,
) -> Scheme:
    new = _sysconfig.get_scheme(
        dist_name,
        user=user,
        home=home,
        root=root,
        isolated=isolated,
        prefix=prefix,
    )
    if _USE_SYSCONFIG:
        return new

    from . import _distutils
```

In addition to the above methods, I don't think the other methods online are very reliable, such as going into the pip init code to change things.
What is the cause of this? I would like to know if I need to reinstall python, is there any downside if I keep the current pip version?
Incidentally, for simple privacy, I changed all my usernames to "MyName", and my python version is 3.9. I have never encountered this kind of problem, and I don't know much about it. I would really appreciate it if you could help me solve it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you may be missing some utilities that come with pip, one thing you can try is to uninstall pip then reinstall using get-pip.

```bash
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py

python3 get-pip.py
```

If this does not work, try to reinstall python